# GPG Cannot Find Keys

Tags: gpg

I transferred my keys using unison to another machine. On the other machine, gpg cannot find any keys.

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys
$
```

`list-secret-keys` does not output anything.

```
$ ls -lha .gnupg/
total 76K
drwx------   5 alex alex 4,0K Mär  8 23:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 116 alex alex  36K Mär  8 23:11 ..
drwx------   2 alex alex 4,0K Mär  8 23:38 crls.d
-rw-------   1 alex alex 2,9K Dez 15  2017 dirmngr.conf
-rw-------   1 alex alex 5,1K Dez 15  2017 gpg.conf
drwx------   2 alex alex 4,0K Mär  8 23:38 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------   2 alex alex 4,0K Mär  8 23:38 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-------   1 alex alex   32 Dez 15  2017 pubring.kbx
-rw-------   1 alex alex   32 Mär  8 23:38 pubring.kbx~
-rw-------   1 alex alex 1,2K Dez 15  2017 trustdb.gpg
```

but the files are there..

On the first machine:

```
$ ls -lha .gnupg/
total 44K
drwx------  5 alex alex 4,0K Feb 10 22:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 92 alex alex 4,0K Mär  9 10:14 ..
drwx------  2 alex alex 4,0K Feb 10 22:16 crls.d
-rw-------  1 alex alex 2,9K Dez 26  2017 dirmngr.conf
-rw-------  1 alex alex 5,1K Dez 26  2017 gpg.conf
drwx------  2 alex alex 4,0K Feb 10 20:37 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------  2 alex alex 4,0K Feb 10 20:37 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r--  1 alex alex 2,0K Feb 10 20:37 pubring.kbx
-rw-------  1 alex alex   32 Dez 26  2017 pubring.kbx~
-rw-------  1 alex alex 1,3K Feb 10 22:14 trustdb.gpg



$ gpg --list-secret-keys 
/home/alex/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-----------------------------
sec   rsa3072 2019-02-10 [SC] [expires: 2021-02-09]
      9806B421CC66EC0E4F1xxxxxxxxxx1B700F021CA
uid           [ultimate] A K <ak@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa3072 2019-02-10 [E] [expires: 2021-02-09]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `pubring.kbx` is sized 2,0K on the first machine, but only 32 bytes on the second machine. So either the file has different contents or the transfer was incomplete.

The timestamp is older on the second machine too, so I'd guess the second machine got an out-of-date version of the file for some reason.

Comment: On the other machine there is no secring.gpg as well. See edited answer.

Comment: You meant "edited question", right? Anyway, here's an edited answer for you.

Comment: Simple as this, the file was somehow only 32 bytes, dont know why. makes me think about the reliability of [unison](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison)..